# Can't refresh dynamic pages in Nextjs

Tags: next.js

When using localhost, I can refresh dynamic pages in `Next.js` without any issues. However, after running the export command and deploying the site using the out folder, I encounter an error when trying to refresh dynamic pages, which shows a 404 not found error.

Can I solve this problem without removing export command?

```
import { Box, Typography } from '@mui/material'
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import View from 'src/views/client/View'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'


const ClientView = () => {

  const router = useRouter();
  const { id } = router.query;

    // Use state to store the ID and update it when available
    const [clientId, setClientId] = useState(id);

    useEffect(() => {
      // Update the state when the ID changes
      setClientId(id);
    }, [id]);
  

  return (
    <Box>

      <View id={clientId} />

      

    </Box>
  )
}
```

export default ClientView